# How can I find out which version of CSS my browser is using?

Tags: css

Is there a way find out which version of CSS a browser is using?  Most of my end users use their phones, but some don't, and those who don't are amenable to telling me their CSS version if we can figure out what it is.  The latest CSS version has elements and styles that will fix some problems I've been having, if I can write code just for it.

Comment: Use Google analystics to check which broswers they use

Comment: You should ask about their browser and then look up which css properties/technologies it supports.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers support CSS 3. It's been released in 2011.

Despite that, they have differences in support of its features.

Have a look at [W3 CSS Browser Support Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)